# ffmpeg not detecting trim frames edited by quicktime

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, quicktime

I have an h264 that was trimmed using Quicktime 7 and exported as a new movie. Opening the movie in quicktime, the trimmed frames appear to no longer exist.  However, when I convert the movie using ffmpeg the trimmed frames reappear.  I also tried to grab a specific frame using -ss and the frame is incorrect as ffmpeg is not recognizing the trim and using in essence the wrong time.

Is there a way to get ffmpeg to recognize the in/out points set by quicktime?

Additionally is there a way to read the in trim value and pass the offset time to ffmpeg?

Comment: Try with ffmpeg 3.2. One of the comments in the change log is "extended mov edit list support" which might fix the issue you're seeing.